# Launch Script After Device is Connected by Polling Device Manager

Tags: python

I'm writing a script that will be started on boot (probably via a batch file). This script will be used to detect when two devices are connected to the computer (specifically a WiiMote and Balance Board). These are paired via bluetooth with Toshiba Bluetooth Stack but also show up in the device manager as human interface devices as "HID-compliant game controller". 
After this script detects that the WiiMote and Balance Board are connected it will launch a batch file that launches GlovePIE (emulates keyboard and mouse) and a game coded with pygame. The game and GlovePIE are both done.

Right now I'm stuck at detecting a successful connection of the devices.
I'm only using Python because it's what I know and what the other program associated with this one are coded in. If anyone has a more elegant solution please let me know.

My thoughts on detecting that the WiiMote and Balance Board are connected:
1. Find where at in the Toshiba Bluetooth Program it indicates a successful pairing of both devices.
2. Poll device manager for two HID-compliant game controllers. This method assumes that no other controllers will ever be connected which for my case is true.
3. Open to suggestions for other approaches.

I couldn't find much documentation on the Toshiba program so I started on finding a way to interact with the device manager.

I found a Python module that interfaces with the device manager [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/infi.devicemanager)
I was able to use the module to get a list of all devices in the device manager. The module only has support for category sorting by disks, scsi devices, volumes, and storage controllers; not human interface devices.

The variable assigned to the list of all devices is all_dev.
I presume this is a list and not a tuple because "type(all_dev) is list" returns true. Also "len(all_dev)" returns 172.

Here's the current main issue:
If I print all_dev it gives a very long list in brackets "[]" with individual items in greater/less than  signs "<>".
If I pick one of these items such as  and search for it in the list like:

```
>>>  "<HID-compliant game controller>" in all_dev
False
```

however if run:

```
>>> x = "test"
>>> all_dev.append(x)
>>> "test" in all_dev
True
```

Same thing happens when I use the count function, 1 for test 0 for anything else.

If I can find out why the in function always returns false I should hopefully be able to write the rest of the script.

Here is what the first part of the program looks like with only part of the list output (much too long).

```
>>> from infi.devicemanager import DeviceManager
>>> dm = DeviceManager()
>>> all_dev = dm.all_devices
>>> print all_dev
[<USB Root Hub>, <Performance Counters for Windows Driver>, <Generic volume shadow copy>, <Generic volume>, <System speaker>, <VirtualBox Service>, <Generic volume shadow copy>, <KSecPkg>, <Remote Desktop Device Redirector Bus>, <Bluetooth RFHID>, <PEAUTH>, <ViewSonic VX1935wm-5 >, <aswStm>, <Terminal Server Keyboard Driver>, <Extended IO Bus>, <VirtualBox USB Monitor Driver>, <Link-Layer Topology Discovery Mapper I/O Driver>, <Bluetooth HID Port>]
```

Comment: Can you provide a couple of lines of what printing `all_dev` looks like?

Comment: Perhaps you can add it to your question in a code block - I suspect some auto formatting in the comments is removing essential things like quotation marks, and it will be better formatted.

Comment: The output is now displayed above in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Those look like [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) objects, one for each category of device.

If you want to get all of the individual devices, you can enumerate each generator, something like

```
[list(category) for category in all_dev]
```

will give you a list of lists of devices in each category. Then you can search that list of lists for the device you're looking for. You could flatten the list, and check if the device you want is that flat list:

```
'dev_I_want' in [item for category in all_dev for item in list(category)]
```

but this assumes that `list(a_category)` returns a simple list with just device names - it might be more complicated.

Comment: If I run help(all_dev) one of the first statements is: "list(iterable) -> new list initialized from iterable's items" and interable is listed under the defined methods of all_dev.    So perhaps if I can find out what the interables are thats a way of splitting it.     Also the [list(category) for category in all_dev] returns Traceback/TypeError. However I wasn't sure when I was supposed to replace category with a specific category name. Running all_dev(Human Interface Devices) or even one word categories like processors returned errors.

Comment: Generators and iterables [are really closely related](http://excess.org/article/2013/02/itergen1/) `all_dev` is a list so you index into it with an integer index like `all_dev[0]`. You can try getting the first element of the list with `device_iterator = all_dev[0]` and printing `device_iterator.next()` to see if that iterator has any elements.